# Is there way to update multiple rows in the same table, with different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL 2014, is there way to update multiple rows in the same table, with different values?

I have a table of costs for components and periodically I need to change the costs for all the individual components.

Currently, I do the following :

```
UPDATE table1 SET cost = '250' WHERE component = 'bicycle'
UPDATE table1 SET cost = '90' WHERE component = 'chainsaw'
UPDATE table1 SET cost = '0.10' WHERE component = 'overripe banana'
```

etc.

This seems a little inefficient to my mind, so is there a better way to do this? Something like an INSERT INTO table1 VALUES () but for an UPDATE statement.

So instead of running 10000 UPDATE statements, I can run one that updates multiple different rows.

Maybe it's not inefficient, which is fine too.

Thanks

Comment: What did you do to end up with those nasty so-called "smart" quotes in the query? They are wrong for SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use a [table-value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) (just like with an INSERT) and a JOIN to create your update:

```sql
UPDATE old
SET old.cost = new.cost
FROM table1 old  
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
        ('bicycle', 250.00), 
        ('Chainsaw', 90.00), 
        ('overripe banana', 0.10)
    ) AS new(Component,Cost) ON new.Component = old.Component
```

Answer (score 0):

i also was looking for the solution on this and i cant find any.. i later on comeup with this solution incase someone is also having trouble with this..

```
UPDATE table1 
SET cost = CASE component 
WHEN 'bicycle' THEN '250' 
WHEN 'chainsaw' THEN '90' 
WHEN 'overripe banana' THEN '0.10' 
ELSE cost 
END
WHERE component IN ('bicycle', 'chainsaw', 'overripe banana');
```